# Program crashes when using one RDP client but not another

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop

I have a server we remote into via RDP. The server is Windows Server 2012 R2 Std and most of the clients are Windows 10 but some are Windows 7.

There is one program on the remote server that we use, it works for everyone except two people.

From their computer they connect using the windows default RDP client and try to run the program but it shows the "This program stopped working" error message.
In the event logs it has the following error message.

> Faulting application name: BsGUI.exe, version: 2.14.0.0, time stamp: 0x552521ac
>   Faulting module name: comctl32.ocx, version: 6.0.81.5, time stamp: 0x3802598b
>   Exception code: 0xc000041d Fault offset: 0x00020f51
>   Faulting process id: 0x2a4 Faulting application start time:
>   0x01d3f9379b9c9c5c
>   Faulting application path:
>   D:\BsGUI\BsGUI.exe
>   Faulting module path:
>   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\comctl32.ocx
>   Report Id:
>   debe6387-652a-11e8-80d2-0010f31dccb9
>   Faulting package full name:
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

This happens no matter what user they are connecting to or if it is a new or existing session.
They try connecting from another computer and it works.

I got them to copy all of the settings from my RDP client, they have tried running the RDP client as an administrator, nothing seems to work.

When I download another remote desktop client from the windows app store I get the same problem as them, when they try same RDP client they still have the problem.

I have found similar issues on other forums online but none of them have any solutions that work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

We experience similar issues with a VB6 app which using comctl32.ocx. The treeview became insensitive, no repaint, but no crash either, like if it was not receiving events. The app's File menu was working and you could exit etc. Fixed by changing comctl32.ocx to mscomctl.ocx that delivers an equivalent treeview. We did this after learning that mscomctl.ocx was 'newer' (VB6 vs. comctl32.ocx from VB5) and that it used a different messaging scheme (http://computer-programming-forum.com/65-vb-controls/5bbc99718d08607f.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue, but can't switch out the ocx.

This seems to be a permanent fix for issues with comctl32 controls failing during/after an rdp session on Windows 10.

Services.msc, disable 'Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service'.  Reboot.